# I best versus I had better

Tags: grammar

So today I was playing a video game where a child said "I best get going" (I'm sure she said I instead of I'd because it was a typed dialogue). Now, I know that this had the same meaning as "I had better get going" and that you can drop the "had" in informal English. However, is is the same case here? Is the correct form "I had best get going" and the child dropped the "had" due to informal English?

Thanks a lot for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"best" implies a number of possibilities

"better" implies a choice of two

It's possible that the child said "I'd best be going and the "d" sound wasn't obvious. Alternatively the child had misheard the phrase or this was a local dialect.

"I'd better get going" (correct and idiomatic 'standard' English)

"I'd best get going" (grammatically and semantically correct but considered non-standard by some)

"I best/better get going." (dialect or incorrect grammar)

Comment: /d/ before /b/ gets lost fast. Often it's not even pronounced; the speaker makes an apical gesture before the lips close for /b/, but it never gets to the alveolar ridge.

Comment: I'm certain she said it without the " 'd " cause it was a typed dialogue. Thanks a lot anways! +1

Comment: From the song "Ignorance" by Paramore: "I guess I'll go / I'd best be on my way out"

Answer (score 2):

> Is the correct form "I had best get going" and the child dropped the "had" due to informal English?

### Yes.